# PHP return array when scraping with Goutte

Tags: php, api, goutte, laravel-5.1

I'm trying to return an array of items with goutte, I can print them out but I want them in an array, like an API. Here's the sample code. I'm using Laravel 5.1.

```
public function index()
{
    $posts = array();
    $client = new Client();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://www.icetimux.com');

    $crawler->filter('h2 > a')->each(function ($node) use ($posts){
        // print $node->text(); //this prints them, needs to return as an array :(
        array_push($posts, $node->text());
    });
    return $posts;
}
```

All I get back is an empty array.

Comment: Looks fine to me. Although you could use $posts[] = $node->text(); instead of array_push(...), too. Are you sure that an empty array is returned from this function? Maybe $node->text() is not really a string, you could try $posts[] = ''.$node->text(); to make sure that the values are copied and these copies keep existing.

Comment: tried `array_push($posts, (string)$node->text());` and still an empty array. Also tried `$posts[] = ''.$node->text();` and also empty. I see this in the browser `[ ]` (I use JSON view chrome extension)

Comment: And you used json_encode() before sending the array to the client?

Comment: @RhinoDevel yup, still empty. `return json_encode($posts)`

Comment: Is this function supposed to directly send the data to the client? Don't you need to use print instead of return then?!

Comment: @RhinoDevel, no I'm trying to make it a public API, so other devs can just use the json formatted data returned for their apps

Comment: Okay @RhinoDevel I've made some progress, look. now it is returning an array. but the items are all `null`. when I print them out they aren't null.  `public function index()
    {                          
        $client = new Client();
        $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://www.icetimux.com');
        
        $result = $crawler->filter('h2 > a')->each(function ($node){
            $posts = [];
            // print $node->text(); //print them, needs return as an array :(
            $posts[] = $node->text();
        });
        return $result;
    }`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

haha! I did it! check it out!

```
public function index()
{
    $client = new Client();
    $crawler = $client->request('GET', 'http://www.icetimux.com');

    return $result = $crawler->filter('h2 > a')->each(function ($node){
        return $posts[] = $node->text();
    });
}
```

Comment: I was expecting the same results using the same kind of approach that you have shown in your question. I tried it but didn't work. I happened to run it with your solution. Thanks!